# Квантование и дискретизация + кодировка (по сути: реализация АЦП)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dsp

Допустим у меня есть массив данных, я его импортирую и строю по нему график. Так теперь задача состоит в том, чтобы этому графику задать шаг дискретизации и заквантовать его по уровню плюсом еще было бы если помогли бы разобраться с кодированием, чтобы мы могли получить как бы цифровой сигнал, главное, чтобы еще  можно было регулировать эти параметры. Об этом я и прошу помощи, встроенные методы matplotlib пробовал, но они ограничены. Код предлагать не буду, т.к. его нету.
В качестве примера возьмите функцию sin x ограниченную на отрезке [0,10].

Comment: Особо на этом не надо заострять внимания, мне, пожалуйста, суть. А с АЦП, ЦЦП я сам разберусь, у вас я этого не просил.

Comment: Я не понял задачу. Отсчёты уже есть. Что с ними нужно сделать?

Comment: Ладно, зря я эти отсчеты залил, просто возьмите функцию sin x и проделайте с ней манипуляции по задаче.

Comment: Это продолжение вашего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1202804), или это полностью отдельный вопрос?

Answer (score -1):

Ну давайте так для начала попробуем:

```
xmax = 10 #интервал в секундах
x = 0
freq = 100  #частота дискретизации в Гц
ff = 1
xstep = 1 / freq
bits = 16
mult = 1 << (bits - 1) 

while x < xmax:
    y = sin(x*ff) 
    dig = int(y * mul)
    result.append(dig)
    x += чstep
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть как это графически отобразиться, а то так не совсем наглядно.

Comment: Отображайте, мне нечем это сделать. Добавил картинку, сделанную в Delphi с параметрами `freq := 4;  ff := 0.6;  bits := 6;`

Comment: В том и дело, что не получается, просто пустой график.

Comment: Ну значит, проблема не в квантовании, а в рисовании